# how move region specifie map in mapkit xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

I create to one `Mapkit` app that when I click on one button (with name: **Add**) add annotation on the center view map.

Now I want to when click another button (with name: **Moving Center**) my center region moving 100px to top (In other words I scroll move 100px to top)

please help me and guide me how to move scroll on map in `Mapkit` with code?

Comment: post code!!!  what u have did ?

Answer (score 1):

**Use :**

```
[mapView setRegion:myRegion animated:YES];
```

**For centering on user location, you can use the following code:**

```
[mapView setCenterCoordinate:mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

Your `MapView` delegate will need to set the annotation view's dragState back to `MKAnnotationViewDragStateNone`, when the annotation ends or cancels its drag operation.

```
 - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView
                             didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState
                                   fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState
 {
    if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding) 
    {
      // code for when drag ends ...
      [annotationView setDragState:MKAnnotationViewDragStateNone animated:YES];
    }

    else if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateCanceling) 
    {
       // code for when drag cancelled...
       [annotationView setDragState:MKAnnotationViewDragStateNone animated:YES];
    }
 }
```

Comment: my friend you don't understand my question and I tell how to move my map view with code (like when move mapView with my finger but I want do this with code)???

Comment: Try this –mapView:regionWillChangeAnimated: or -mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:

Comment: @DavidR. he told that when another button clicked region will move dynamically with 100 pixel on map. like we move map using finger. but he want to move map using code not using finger.